# Orthogonal projections of permutation matrices are symmetry group of regular simplex?

Tags: gr.group-theory, linear-algebra

Each permutaion $\pi\in S_n$ corresponds to a permutation matrix $P_\pi$ with $(0,1)$ entries. To be more specific, $P_\pi = [e_{\pi(1)},\ldots,e_{\pi(n)}]$, where $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ are standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Note that $P_\pi \mathbb{1}=\mathbb{1}$, where $\mathbb{1}$ is a vector with all $1$ elements. Then we can block diagonalize $P_\pi$ for $\pi\in S_n$  simultaneously. See this  [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3689639/common-eigenvectors-implies-simultaneously-block-diagonalizations) about block diagonalization. There is an orthogonal change of basis $V$ such that 
$$V^t P_\pi V = \begin{bmatrix}
\hat{P_\pi} & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
for all $\pi\in S_n$.
I'm reading a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.08010), which says that $\{\hat{P}_\pi,\pi\in S_n\}$ can be interpreted as the symmetry group of a regular simplex in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. I need more details about why it is true. Thanks for reading! Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: Take the simplex whose vertices are the standard basis vectors on ${\mathbb R}^n$.